# "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" My client is not able to invoke web service

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, keystore

I'm trying to call a web service and send some xml data to it. I was given certificates by the company that hosts the web service and I have imported them to my keystore and have also set the key store in my code.

The company says my IP's are whitelisted and their server is up and running but I keep getting this exception:

```
17:18:00,255 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
17:18:00,255 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
17:18:00,256 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
17:18:00,256 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
17:18:00,257 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
17:18:00,257 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
17:18:00,258 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
17:18:00,258 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
17:18:00,258 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
17:18:00,259 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
17:18:00,259 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
17:18:00,259 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
17:18:00,260 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
17:18:00,260 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
17:18:00,260 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
17:18:00,261 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
17:18:00,261 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
17:18:00,261 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
17:18:00,262 ERROR [stderr] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:
```

This is some of the code I used:

```
   //Start connection
    URL url = new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection con  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //Set HTTP header properties
    con.setConnectTimeout(60000);   
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setUseCaches(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(xml.length()));
    con.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", address);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    userPass = username + ":" + password;
    byte[] encodeBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userPass.getBytes());
    String encode = new String(encodeBytes);
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encode);

    //Set up HTTPS
    HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) con;
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        KeyManagerFactory kmFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(ERPGetProperty.erpGetProperty("pathToKeyStore")));
        TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        try {
            kStore.load(fis, keyStorePass);
            kmFactory.init(kStore, keyStorePass);
            tmFactory.init(kStore);

            context.init(kmFactory.getKeyManagers(), tmFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
            httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
            httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }

            });

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    out = httpsConnection.getOutputStream();
```

Could this be a problem on my end or the server hosting the web service? I have a fast internet connection and not running any firewall as well. Please, I really need help and I've been stuck with this problem for almost a week already.

UPDATE: I used openssl client in order to test host

```
openssl s_client -connect <ip>:port (where ip is the IP address of the host im trying to reach)
```

I get this output from the terminal:

connect: Operation timed out
connect:errno=60

However, using IP address of their testing environment, I'm able to communicate with them and openssl can display their certificate chain, so connection is successful. The production IP address is the one I seem to be having issues with.

UPDATE_2: Used nmap with -P0 flag in order to test ports 80 and 443 of the host server and both of them seem to be filtered. Does this mean my IP address hasn't been whitelisted successfully?

Comment: It's a very vague message you are getting. You can assume that the host is there and alive, but it is not responding. If it was authentication issues, it should give a warning/error. My guesses, wrong/bad connection. Either the port or host/ip are not what you think they are or should be OR (more likely), there is a firewall or other such issue (proxy).

Answer (score 0):

It's a very vague message you are getting. You can assume that the host is there and alive, but it is not responding. You have done enough to simply connect, but there is more that is needed. If it was authentication issues, it would often give a warning/error, but not always. My guesses? wrong/bad connection/protocol.

Either the port or host/ip are not what you think they are or should be OR (more likely), there is a firewall or other such issue (proxy).

I've also seen issues like this talking to Google and other servers. They may not respond if you are not using the correct protocol. They may be waiting for certain info from you. Basically, I say Hi, you say "How can I help you? Who are you?" and then I make a respond and also make a request. I haven't looked too deeply at your code, but this is my experience. Hope it helps.

This is a good reference to the kind of stuff I ran into. Maybe it's more manual than your code, but it worked well for me.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Last bit of advice, go through all of the Exceptions thrown. If you are not getting these, assume that this is not the case and narrow down the problem. Go through all of the Http error codes too. For example, "host not found" and "forbidden" are two errors you are not getting. You should be able to get the error code from the Http socket transaction.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @Idmtwo This was helpful, thank you! I also tried telnetting the IP address along with the port (443) and I just get a connection timeout, can this actually tell me the host server is the one with the problem? Because if they have whitelisted my IP address, I don't see why it can't connect. I have tried different protocols on my client programatically like SSL, TLS, SSLv3, TLSv1 etc and all give me the same issue. Is there anything else I can do to test their web service? I tried SOAPUI but I don't have their wsdl. I'm gonna go through that article you posted and keep researching, thank you!

Comment: @Idmtwo The code just hangs when I call openConnection() method, so It doesn't even print out a response since it can't connect to the server and just throws out the exception.